# Malformed config.xml in Phonegap

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-build

The `config.xml` is failing with malformed error in adobe cloud build. I tried checking for badly closed `<>` tags. I even replaced the file with an earlier version I had that built correctly.

Here is the config.xml **outside of the www folder:**

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.mypackage.name" version="1.3.0">
  <name>Name</name>
  <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
  <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
        <supports-screens
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true" />
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
            <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            </activity>
        </application>
    </gap:config-file>

  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
   <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

And here is the config.xml **inside of the www folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id        = "com.mypackage.name"
    version   = "1.3.0">

<name>Name</name>

<description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>

<author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>

<!-- Define the main entry-point to the application -->
<content src="index.html" />

<!--
    If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
    following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
    permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
-->
<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="14" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
<!--
    Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
    <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" />
-->

<!-- Plugins -->
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <supports-screens
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
    </application>
</gap:config-file>

<!-- Core plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<!--<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />-->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />

<!-- Define app icon for each platform. 
<icon src="icon.png" />-->
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-mdpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-mdpi.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

<!--
    Define access to external domains.

    <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
    <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

    Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
-->
<access origin="*"/>
<!--
   <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
   <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
   <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
-->
<!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
<!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>


</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **config.xml outside of the www folder** uses an undeclared namespace prefix, `android:`.  Fix this by adding

```
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to the root `widget` element.